# Blender freezes often on Alienware M15R4 laptop

Tags: saving

I just do some simple coding on text editor. When I tried to save the file, Blender freezes a lot. I am using Alienware M15R4, with some voltage setting as shown in the screenshot. Does it affect the performance of Blender?
[image]

Comment: Are you working on a server or locally ?

Comment: Locally...@Gorgious